# Console integration toolkit functions from Lightning Component are not running after enabling Locker Service

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service

we had an application up and running, where we had called Salesforce Console Integration Toolkit functions like `sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabId`
and within that `force.console.OpenSubtab(...)` was called.

This application was working fine before enabling Locker Service. After enabling this application is throwing **"sforce: undefined"** error in developer console log and while running Lightning lint on the code base it is throwing **"warning: no-undef 'sforce' is not defined"** and no subtabs are opening.

I have applied the workaround provided in the blog:
[Salesforce lightning CLI error no-undef 'sforce' is not defined](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/151458/salesforce-lightning-cli-error-no-undef-sforce-is-not-defined)

This has removed the warning , but the **Opensubtab** is not working.

Comment: It appears to be a cross domain issue similar to (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/174170/window-opener-a-syntax-gives-permission-denied-to-access-property-a-error/174902#174902.  We are trying to get rid-off cross domain issue using **Windows.postMessage**.  I'll confirm back in case we able to solve the problem.

Comment: This appears to be a known bug to Salesforce : [known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000008k7xQAA)